# Location Services Coordinate System

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile-gps

Which coordinatesystem Windows Phone 7-device is using? If I fetch latitude and longitude with WP 7, are they equivalent to WGS84 and Mercator coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts here.. if you use built in GPS and ask for coordinates, they give you GeoPosition which exposes Latitude / Longitude etc

Bing Maps used with WP7 uses Mercator tile system

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx

If you search msdn you will find various samples. Here's one that I modified a while back
http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2012/06/30/bing-mapcontrol-offline-tiles-solution-wpdev-wp7dev/ it contains many helpers.